# Function with two arguments in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am trying to better understand functions and found an example online but can't get it to work.
I want to solve an equation a, and have two arguments v and r. v= 10 and r=3. Here is my code. What am I missing? Thanks for your insights.

```
solve <- function(r=3,v=10) {
a <- pi*r*(sqrt(r^2+(9*v^2)/pi^2*r^4)) 
}
return(a)
```

Based on inputs. Here is the updated code. But looks like the result is not accurate.

```
solve <- function(r,v){
a <- pi*r*(sqrt(r^2+(9*v^2)/pi^2*r^4)) 
return(a)
}
solve(3,10)
```

R is giving me a result of 810.4933. But the example says the result is 29.9906.
Here is the formula for A:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spynW.png)

Comment: `return(a)` needs to be inside the curly braces `{ ... }`

Comment: @G5W is right, though it can be bad practice to always assume that the return value from an assignment operation returns the whole dataset; for instance, if it is a subsetting assignment (e.g,. `a[is.na(a)] <-  -42` counts the same, it does not return all of `a`). I recommend making the last expression exactly what you want returned (i.e., `a` here), optionally using `return(a)` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I modified my code. It looks like its working. But the result doesnt match the online example. It should be 29,9906, but i am getting 810.4933.
 
solve <- function(r,v){
  a <- pi*r*(sqrt(r^2+(9*v^2)/pi^2*r^4)) 
  return(a)
}
solve(3,10)

Comment: It would help if you update your code in your question, too ([edit]). It's difficult helping when the code shown here is known to be wrong but is not corrected: we can't always know if what you think you did and what you actually did are the same. (FYI, on top of the fact that comments do not format large data or code very well, comments can easily be skipped by readers and/or hidden by the interface. Thanks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the order of operations within math expressions. If you read `?Ops` (kind of obscure, granted), you'll see

```
       2. Group '"Ops"':
            • '"+"', '"-"', '"*"', '"/"', '"^"', '"%%"', '"%/%"'
            • '"&"', '"|"', '"!"'
            • '"=="', '"!="', '"<"', '"<="', '">="', '">"'
```

Which suggests that `*` and `/` are consecutive. Unfortunately, your *denominator* of

```r
... / pi^2*r^4
```

is being interpreted as

```r
(... / pi^2) * (r^4)
```

which brings `r^4` into the numerator.

Add parens to enforce the order of operations.

```r
.../(pi^2*r^4)
```